# Early Lease Termination

Tags: fees, termination, lease

If I am served with a letter from Management indicating that my lease expires  1/29/2020 and it will not get renewed and if i am not out of the apartment by 12/30/2019  will receive an eviction notice. I move out on 12/15/2019. Can I be charged for an early termination fee?

Comment: This seems like more of a legal question.

Comment: Why not ask "Management" directly?

Comment: If your lease ends 1/29/2020 why would you need to be out by 12/30/2019? That bit is confusing.

Comment: @HartCO yeah, and are you still paying for January even though you have to be gone?

Answer (score 1):

> I move out on 12/15/2019. Can I be charged for an early termination fee?

As long as you've paid through the end of the month almost certainly no.

When moving apartments, it's normal to move out a week or two beforehand so you have time to get all your utilities moved and ensure nothing has been left behind.  Especially near Christmas, I would expect a move-out date around the 15th.

If you stay past your lease, I'm not sure what would happen.  Since you have no legal right to stay there past the lease agreement I'm not sure eviction is the right word.  Either way, I wouldn't wait around to find out.

Comment: It is eviction in most jurisdictions. First, depending on where he is he may have an implied rental agreement (have to pay rent until eviction or real move out),m or have to pay a fine. But eviction is also the term used to get squatters out - in most jurisdictions it is the same process, same name.

Comment: Surely this answer is dependent on the jurisdiction, which we don't know.